# What do the numbers mean in thematic overview

Tags: piano

In some printings of Beethoven's complete piano sonatas there are thematic overviews, i. e. a page with the first beats. There are also numbers, e. g. besides
op. 2, no. 1 it reads "10", besides op. 2, no. 3 it reads "13 1/2".
What do these numbers mean?
See here (second page)

https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/03062/qroj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are prices. Those first two pages are basically ads for other sheet music you can buy from the same publisher. It’s like Siri/Google recommendations (“based on your playing history”) 100 years ago.

Comment: If this is correct, sheet music was rather pricey in those days.  Here's an 1875 Montgomery Ward catalogue for comparison; the Hammerklavier sonata costs more than a large leather trunk with a canvas cover (page 81): https://archive.org/details/catalogueno13spr00mont/page/10/mode/2up.  In my research I also found a bootleg edition of Tom Sawyer that sold for $2.75 but I couldn't find the price of the authorized edition.

Comment: Yes, but the answer of @Todd Wilcox is plausible. I never would have come to this because of the notation with fractions "1/2". (BTW: On page 20 of the link provided they write "Price $1.50" and not "$1 1/2").

Comment: @phoog If it’s old enough we don’t know whether those were dollars or cents. Although US half cent coins were only minted through 1857